# C# Multi Thread and Read/Write large text file

Tags: c#, multithreading

I wan to speed up my tool with multi thread to read/write text file
Here how I start - I think I need 7 thread

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() => process(files[i], i));
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
}
```

And my func

```
void process(string file,int threadnumber)
{
    // display thread number
    // filter text 
    // read - write
}
```

But when I start:

```
Thread: 3 start
Thread: 3 start
Thread: 3 start
Thread: 4 start
Thread: 5 start
Thread: 6 start
Thread: 7 start
```

Why my tool don't start thread 1 2 3 4 5 6 7.. few threads duplicate - meaning read and write same file and error.

Please give me advise.

Comment: You have only 1 "i". At time i=3, thread0, 1, and 2 are started. So, at that time i is 3. In Multithreading always sychronized, for example : files[i] and i. If you run this inside thread : "Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);" then you can see, each thread has different id.

Comment: Capturing a for-loop variable is a [standard C# bug](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/).

Comment: Try to do it without a lambda, and you will understand the issue better; the issue being that you are calling `process` from within a lambda and using the current value of `i`, as opposed to "freezing" the value of `i` when you create your lambda. Also, there is no guarantee that the start routines will be called in the same order as the thread creation

Comment: Since I see you're using my solution [in your new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38311275/c-sharp-read-and-write-large-text-file), I'd appreciate if you marked my answer as accepted, _**if it solved your problem, that is**_. -- Marking an answer as accepted can be done by pressing the check mark on the left of the answer. Doing so will mark the question as resolved and will reward the answerer with 15 reputation points, and the asker with 2 reputation points. It will also indicate to other users having similar problems that this was the solution that worked for you.

Comment: What I explained above is also explained in the [**Tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), which is a pretty good thing to read if you're new here. :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how fast the loop iterates and how fast a thread starts, there is a chance that by the time that a thread actually starts the `i` variable might have changed.

You must declare a new variable, for each thread, that is not changed:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    int j = i; //New variable set to the current 'i'.
    Thread thread = new Thread(() => process(files[j], j));
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
}
```

In the above the `j`-variable will get the same value as the current `i`, and won't change even if the loop continues to iterate.